# How to call drupal_bootstrap from custom file in subfolder?

Tags: 7, bootstrapping

I'm trying to call `drupal_bootstrap` from 'temp.php' in a subfolder called 'custom' my code as follow:

```
chdir('../');
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

Once I call the temp.php I get Drupal homepage.

I also tried an explicit physical path but with no use, code as follow:

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', '/var/htdocs/drupal7');
require_once '../includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

temp.php located under the following folder structure:

```
- var
-- htdocs
--- drupal7
---- custom 
----- temp.php
```

Answer (score 6):

I wrote a short post on this here: http://www.csdesignco.com/content/using-drupal-data-functions-and-session-variables-external-php-script

Basically, you only need to do what `index.php` does, but you can elevate the bootstrap to whatever level you need:

```
<?php
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
$base_url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_SESSION);
?>
```

So, for instance, if you just wanted to get something form the database (security aside, this is just an example):

```
<?php
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']); // Define the DRUPAL_ROOT constant which is used in many places.
$base_url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; // Again, this is used in many places.
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc'; // Include the boostrap file.
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_SESSION); // Start things up to whatever level you need.

print db_query("SELECT title FROM {node} WHERE nid = :nid", array(':nid' => $_GET['nid']))->fetchColumn();
?>
```

you could hit `example.com/my-file.php?nid=123` to see the node title for node 123.

I also wrote a tiny function which you can find in this issue (http://drupal.org/node/1922406) where I needed to get the current user's session but didn't want to elevate Drupal's bootstrap to DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_SESSION as the page load goes from ~ 20 milliseconds to over 1,000 milliseconds:

```
function _mymodule_js_session_user() {
  $session_name = session_name();
  if (!empty($session_name)) {
    if ($uid = db_query("SELECT uid FROM {sessions} WHERE sid = :sid", array(':sid' => $_COOKIE[$session_name]))->fetchColumn()) {
      $account = new stdClass();
      $account->uid = $uid;
      $account->roles = array();
      $account->roles[DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID] = 'authenticated user';
      $account->roles += db_query("SELECT r.rid, r.name FROM {role} r INNER JOIN {users_roles} ur ON ur.rid = r.rid WHERE ur.uid = :uid", array(':uid' => $account->uid))->fetchAllKeyed(0, 1);
      return $account;
    }
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your idea, unfortunately it gave me the same result because my code located in a subfolder. It still return Drupal homepage.

Comment: Try `define('DRUPAL_ROOT', '/var/htdocs/drupal7'); $base_url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/drupal7';`

Comment: +1 I tried the above code on fresh/new Drupal installation and it worked fine, Thanks. But still have problem with my current Drupal package.

Comment: This solution works for me also! Thx!

Comment: Why do we need to define `$base_url`?

Answer (score 5):

take a look at http://drupal.org/project/js they implemented a custom js.php that bootstraps drupal.

```
/**
 * @file
 * Callback page that serves custom JavaScript requests on a Drupal installation.
 */

/**
 * @var The Drupal root
 */
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());

/**
 * @} End of "Required core files".
 */

/**
 * @name Required core files
 * @{
 * The minimal core files required to be able to run a js request
 */
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/common.inc';
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/module.inc';
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/unicode.inc';
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/file.inc';
/**
 * @} End of "Required core files".
 */

// Do basic bootstrap to make sure the database can be accessed
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_DATABASE);
```

Comment: The above code will not work because my temp.php file in a subfolder and it will return warning because the the path is wrong. It work fine if my file under the root folder.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/function.chdir.php might help you out. but after all this is not about php programming.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the help. Still my Drupal package is rendering the homepage with wrong css and javascript paths :(

Comment: you can always define the base path in your settings.php

Comment: welcome back to Drupal SE. The code I posted in my question should be the correct way of doing it. My problem was with Devel module, so I disabled it and everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this should be enough (or at least, it was enough for me to run Drupal (7.44 version) functions from `test.php` file **located in the site root folder**):

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```